# Export Sketch text strings to Android string.xml?

Tags: android-studio, sketchapp, string.xml

This may be a crazy question - but has anyone managed to export text strings from Sketch into a text file in some a structured way?

For example, I want to export the text element/layer name (for example, home_welcome) and the text value (for example, Welcome!) to a text file.

Ultimately, I want to use this text file as the basis for a string.xml file in an Android project.

I've tried using this Sketch plugin (https://github.com/exevil/Sketch-Export-Text), but it only exports the text string values.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Having some luck with the `sketchtool` CLI: https://developer.sketch.com/cli/

Exports just about every piece of data in your Sketch files as JSON. Now just need to wrestle with extracting only the data I need...